# Cant access as single user mode - what can we do to recover Linux machine

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, kernel-panic

since our production server not startup ( very important server - Rhel 7.2 )

we try to access as single user mode according to the link - https://www.tecmint.com/boot-into-single-user-mode-in-centos-7/

after entering the single user mode details using VMconsole , Linux stop on the following

[image]

what we can do from this stage in order to recover the production server?

Comment: Do you have a good VM snapshot or backup?

Comment: The top line on the screenshot (please transcribe rather than post images) is the key, "Unable to mount root fs". So at this time the kernel has crashed. Another boot is required.  The timestamps being 6 seconds suggests that it may have been waiting for something to become available.

Comment: no we not have snapshot or backup

Comment: we performed 3-4 reboots but without help , what we could do?

Comment: It's RHEL so you'll have a support licence. Call them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the GRUB boot menu includes multiple kernel versions, try booting with an older version. (There should always be at least the current kernel and the kernel used by the OS installer: the latter has a version number like `0-rescue-<numbers>`.

If the boot is successful with an older kernel, then the problem might be a damaged/missing initramfs file. This is pretty common if your `/boot` filesystem ran out of disk space while installing a kernel update package, for example.

(Each kernel version has its own initramfs file, so if the problem was caused during the most recent update, the older kernel and its initramfs will most likely work.)

If the system is otherwise running normally with the old kernel, you can use a command like

```
mkinitrd /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-327.el7.img 3.10.0-327.el7
```

to recreate the initramfs file for the new kernel.

But if booting with an older kernel fails too, the problem might be something else. In that case, you should perform a rescue mode boot from the installation media. In the case of VMware, that means making sure the virtual hardware includes a virtual CD-ROM drive, and "inserting" an ISO image of a RHEL 7.x installation media (preferably 7.2 or newer) to the virtual CD drive, and telling the VM to boot from CD.

Once the GRUB boot menu of the installation media appears, select "Troubleshooting" and then "Rescue a RedHat Linux system". The installation program will load and ask for language & keyboard settings as with a normal installation, but then it will switch to rescue mode. It will even offer to automatically mount the disks of the installation-to-be-rescued for you, if that OS installation is not too badly damaged. Then it will give you a root command prompt you can use to further troubleshoot and apply fixes as necessary.

When in a rescue boot environment, your real root filesystem will be mounted at `/mnt/sysimage`. To be able to access it using normal pathnames (= without prefixing /mnt/sysimage to *everything*), you can use the `chroot /mnt/sysimage` command, which will also be suggested to you just before entering the rescue command prompt.

After using the `chroot /mnt/sysimage` command, you should be able to use any shell commands your installed OS has available. For example, if you find that the initramfs files for your kernels are missing from `/boot`, you can use the `mkinitrd` command (as described above) to recreate them.

Answer (score 2):

Try booting with installation media, and diagnose/fix from there. **Back up anything important!** Chances are the machine or the system is broken, needing a migration or a reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the latest kernel always panicked but the previous worked fine. This allowed me to login and see what was happening luckily.

One of the devs had changed the "root" group to "oot", and subsequently /boot was not owned by id 1000 (root). When i ran the yum install, it said unable to write kernel to /boot which led to my discovery... After some manual edits to the shadow file and some chown -R action, the new kernel installed as expected.

TLDR, check perms to system files and make sure no one broke the root account info.